# Displaying Captcha image in php

Tags: php, captcha

When I display captcha image, I got following error : -

Warning (2): imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font
I have saved font file on root.

This is my code -

```
$path = fullpath to site images folder
$imgname = 'noise.jpg';
$imgpath  = $path.'/'.$imgname;

$captchatext = md5(time());
$captchatext = substr($captchatext, 0, 5);
$_SESSION['captchatext'] = $captchatext;
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgpath); 
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$font = site_root_directory_path/BIRTH_OF_A_HERO.ttf;
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);
$text = $_SESSION['captchatext'];
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: On who's root did you saved? Website's or Machine? Apache does not have access to root folders. Make sure `site_root_directory_path` is an actual path to that font and it's accessible by apache.

Comment: This looks like a very weak captcha, since it uses a fixed background and a fixed font with a fixed color on a straight line. No warped text, no added noise (eg: lines, decoys, etc.), nothing that would make this even challenging for a computer.

Comment: @ Mihai Iorga : I have saved on website's root directory. When I am accessing it directly, it prompts to save the font.

Comment: How to access the font ?

Comment: But, the path need to be absolute.

Comment: What do you mean by absolute path here ? Please.

Comment: No, not webpath. Server path.

Answer (score 1):

You font path needs to be absolute or relative to the script.

For example:

```
$font = '/var/www/website/BIRTH_OF_A_HERO.ttf'; - absolute
$font = '../../BIRTH_OF_A_HERO.ttf'; - relative
```

Comment: I am using cake php and I have saved font file in webroot folder.

Comment: and you need to make the path work. doesn't matter what framework you are using.